# How to stop video in UITableViewCell when new screen is pushed

Tags: swift, uitableview, avfoundation, avplayer

I do have tab bar controller with few tabs - one of the tabs looks like this:

- I have a table view filled with cells
- Some of the cells contains `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer`
- I'm using a delegate method `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath` to stop videos that are scrolled out of the visible area

What I need:

- When I push a new controller, I need to stop video that is currently playing
- When I tap on different tab in tab bar, I need to stop video as well

I tried to implement `func willMove(toWindow newWindow: UIWindow?)`, but it has one annoying side-effect: I have to manually setup dismiss gesture for all the pushed screens.

Any alternative ideas about how to solve that problem? Thanks guys

Comment: What about `viewDidDisappear(_:)` ?

Comment: He needs to do it inside the cell context, for what I understood.

Comment: turn off the player on that cell after didselect

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in `viewWillDisappear` function of a `UIViewController` which has the video cells.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        (cell as VideoCell).stopVideo()
    }
}
```